# how to manually install hid-logitech-dj module?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, logitech

I'm running ubuntu mate on raspberry pi2. Logitech k400r keyboard w/touchpad  works fine with generic driver but when I wanted to add logitech m525 mouse using the same unifying receiver, I had to use Solaar for pairing. I installed solaar but it can't find unifying receiver, "no logitech receiver found" error. I think solaar needs hid-logitech-dj module loaded to work. So, how can I manually add/install  hid-logitech-dj module? I also tried ltunify, it's the same...thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
modprobe hid-logitech-dj
```

then disconnect and reconnect the receiver.
This worked for me on a desktop Ubuntu. Of course this is not persistent, but was enough for using ltunify for pairing.

For a persistent setup you will have to tinker with udev rules...